# I build a select and i need when i refresh the page he shows what i have select before

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I tried a lot of things and can't figure out what can I do. I build a select and I need when I refresh the page it shows what I have selected before, because every time it will update the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(window).on('load', function () {

            $('.lavagem_01').selectpicker('selectAll');

            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
                'selectedText': 'cat',
                'showIcon': true
            });


            $( "select" ).change( displayVals );

            function displayVals() {
                var etiquetas = $( this ).val() || [];
                var product_id = $( this ).attr("id");

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'salvar.php', //This is the current doc
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ({product_id: product_id, etiquetas: etiquetas}),
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("R:  " + data);
                    }
                }); 


                //alert('Produto: ' + product_id + ' - Etiquetas: ' + etiquetas);
            }
```

Comment: please explain properly..

Comment: you need to save it in a cookie or a session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) would help.

For more persistent storage, try [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage), instead.

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Djs/16/

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');

var lastIndex = sessionStorage.getItem('lastIndex');

// lastIndex, pulled from sessionStorage, is valid, so load into select.
if (typeof lastIndex !== 'undefined')
{
    select.selectedIndex = lastIndex;
}

select.addEventListener('change',function(e)
{
    // Store the chosen index value, here
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastIndex',select.selectedIndex);
});
```

Notice that, after setting the select field option, you can either click "Run" or refresh the page, and the field will retain its value.

And again, if `sessionStorage` is not persistent enough for you, simply replace it with `localStorage`.